# why does wrinkling happen when i shell my part outward? (solidworks)

Tags: solidworks

i am relatively new to solidworks and would appreciate any help. I am creating a hollow pipe as shown in the picture below. I did this by using lofted boss/base for 3 circular sketches and the shelling it. I wanted to make the pipe 2mm in thickness. However there were 2 problems with the shell command.
[image]

1. I get the following error when i try to shell inward, which i don't really understand. [image]
2. So i tried a workaround by reducing the dimensions of my part and then shelling outward. However, ugly artifacts occurred when i made the thickness too large.

My question is: Why do these errors occur, and how do i prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Please can you share the file? (Via link to Dropbox, Google drive, WeTransfer, FileDropper etc). It will be more instructive to demo the solution on your part than to try and recreate your problems

Comment: Make sure all your sketches are fully defined.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Here's the download link to the file: https://we.tl/t-yuqm7u4MBH